# What data structure should i use to support insert, delete and random selection?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I need to create a data structure of integers which supports the following operations -

1. Insert item at given position  (Add item position)
2. Delete item from given position  (Delete position)
3. randomly select any given position (Select position)
4. Random shuffling the items.

I need to maintain one head. which is represented by (). See the example for more details.

```
Ex- 

lets say my initial state is 
(1) 2 3 4 5
Where () represents my current head

After Add 6 2
state  - (1) 6 2 3 4 5

After Delete 5
state  - (1) 6 2 3 5

After Select 3
state  - 1 6 (2) 3 5

After shuffle 
state  - 5 (2) 6 1 3
 shuffle will shuffle all the items randomly. But will preserve the head.
```

Comment: It depends on alot of thing, if you expect small amount of elements (like 20 or less) probably vector is superior. Tho, for large number of elements inserting and deleting for example from middle of the vector is expensive...

Comment: `std::vector` seems like it'd do the trick.

Comment: @Kerrek SB  I tied array which involves items movement in case of insert and delete of in between items. Then i thought of link list also. But most of my operations involves random access so  link list was not a good idea. I explored the option of Array + Hash. I was looking if there is some better option available which i am not aware of.

Comment: @JitendraRathor: Maybe a Boost.Multiindex with both a sequence index and node-based storage then?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you don't have *specific* reasons to choose something else, a vector will do fine. If you have like 6 objects, a program using a vector will have completed before another program has even allocated the first node in a linked list.

Comment: LPs Its not homework. I have tried Array, list,Array+hash. I searched on the web as well. but could not find any better data structure which performs better in all my cases so thought of asking for help from experienced people.

Comment: @LPs SO:s policy is that it doesn't matter _why_ someone needs an answer. All questions must meet the same quality criteria no matter if they are regarding beginner homework or space shuttle firmware. So "smells like homework" comments are not constructive or relevant.

Comment: @Lundin This question, in my opinion, does not meet the requirement. I flagged it. BTW if the comment could be rude for someone, I can cancel it.

Comment: @LPs I have tried vector as well. But one thing i observed is that all the insert doesn't take same amount of time everytime. at specific intervals insert is taking 5/6 times more than normal time taken. I am assuming that it is because where current size is full. new memory (existing size + some const ) is allocated and data is being copied.  I still don't have solution.Can you please tell if you have any solution?

Comment: I find the question interesting, as a tradeoff between speed of insert/delete (favoring lists) and finding elements by index (favoring arrays). Finding a technique that matches both requirements is interesting. It is not a dumb question. I voted it up.

Answer (score 0):

Create bins of size 2k each, and have n/k of those (so total number of allocated space is 2n).

- Each "bin" will know its start index and end index.
- When inserting, first find the relevant bin. This takes O(n/k) time if using linear search. Add the element to the bin (assume it's not full for the moment), and shift to the right all elements in that specific bin. Then, update all bins after the bin you just modified. This will take `O(n/k + k)` time.
- Deletion is similar to addition, and is again done in `O(n/k + k)` time.
- Select: Find the relevant bin (again, linear search will give you `O(n/k)`, and the item's place in it is found in `O(1)`). Note however you can find the bin using binary search in `O(log(n/k))` time, so selection is `O(log(n/k))`.
- Shuffle using [fisher yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) in `O(n)`.

In addition, when bin is full, just reallocate the entire array, and if needed - increase bins size. This operation is `O(n)`, and is done after at least `O(k)` insertions, so when talking about amortized times it's still `O(n/k)` per insertion for it.

All we have to do now, is find optimal `k`, so we want to minimize `n/k + k`.

```
f(k) = n/k + k, 0 < k <=n
df/dk = n*-1*k^(-2) + 1 = 0
1/n = 1/k^2
n = k^2
sqrt(n) = k
```

So, for optimal choice of `k` we need `k=sqrt(n)`, and we get the complexities:

- Insertion: `O(sqrt(n))`
- Deletion: `O(sqrt(n))`
- Selection: `O(log(sqrt(n))) = O(log(n))`
- Shuffle: `O(n)`